# How to see number of total queries made to Oracle over time period?

Tags: oracle, statistics, oracle11g

I have a simple need: I need to see how many queries a vendor's application is running against our Oracle (11g r2) database. Is there a way to query a system table (e.g. `v$...`) to see this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [V$SQLSTATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/dynviews_3065.htm)? I'm not sure how you're going to differentiate the vendor-specific SQL from other SQL that might have run, but this could give you a feel for what has been running.

If all you're interested in is what's happening now, then perhaps [V$SQLAREA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3060.htm) is what you want.

Comment: That sounds right based on the description. Unfortunately, turns out the DBA have barred access to those tables. *sigh*

Comment: Depending on your relationship with them, perhaps you could explain your need and see if there was some sort of accomodation that could be worked out, even temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

v$SQL has some stats and can tell you module and action (see dbms_application_info)
v$SQLSTATS has more statistics but less ability to determine application source.

DBAs can be overly protective and take the easy way out banning access to really useful stuff.
See if a view (that masks sensitive info) can be created and granted to you so you have access to the really useful stuff while not to the sensitive stuff.